# Multiple form (or multiple page) page

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I need to make a section in my web application that has multiple forms, but only one form should be shown at a time. Those form are very similar (the difference is a select box instead of a radio button, etc.). The active form should be selected using a select box, or some kind of a tabbed menu on top. Forms are used for insert data with mysql and php. What is the most easiest way of doing this?

Comment: You need to use AJAX using jQuery or any other client side library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each form tag an id tag and then add an onchange listener to your dropdown select box.  In the listener toggle the CSS display attribute of your forms.

```
<select name="..." id="change" onchange='OnChange(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);'>
    <option val="form_id_1">form 1</option>
</select>
```

Then the javascript would be:

```
<script language="text/javascript">
<!--
function OnChange(form_id)
{

    document.getElementById("first_form_id").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("second_form_id").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("third_form_id").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("fourth_form_id").style.display = 'none';

    document.getElementById(form_id).style.display = 'block';

    return true;
}
//-->
</script>
```

This hides all the forms at first, then shows the one you wanted to select

Comment: I figured it out by myself, but thanks alot for the answer =)
I did it by making forms inside hidden divs (that become visible). Now i just have to find out how to position the divs on a desired place.